# Read IIS web site name from php

Tags: php, iis, iis-7.5

I have a PHP web site running on IIS.  How would I read the web site name into a variable using PHP?

Here is how I would accomplish this in .net using

```
string WebSiteName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
```

How can I accomplish the same thing in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it into the [`$_SERVER[]` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is the name of the server or virtual host that owns the served script.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is extracted from the `Host:` HTTP header of the request.

In theory they should contain the same value. In the real world I think `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is more reliable (in fact, it is what the browser requested).

*(I think `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is the one returned by the .net code you posted).*